# Sonarquberunner check c# code

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I may introduce a custom rule that checks our code whether it contains a deprecated using.

```
using foo.bar;

class FooClass {
```

Is there a possibility by custom rules or Sonar itself to check this code and fail the build due to usage of deprecated package foo.bar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to work backward:

- You can fail the build [with a Jenkins pipeline](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline)
- if your analysis fails the [Quality Gate](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates).
- You can't fail the Quality Gate for issues from a specific rule, but you can fail it for new issues of a certain severity

So I would recommend that you set add your new rule to your Quality Profile at Blocker severity (after all, you want it to *block* the build), set a quality gate error condition on New Blocker Issues and set up your Jenkins pipeline to respond appropriately.

If you're not using Jenkins, or not using Pipelines, there is also the [Build Breaker plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker), altho [its use is not recommended](https://blog.sonarsource.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! 
And which template do i have to use to check our code regarding to the using statement?

Comment: @GGMU1878 that's an entirely different discussion. For C# you'll need to write a custom Roslyn checker and that's far beyond the scope of comments on an unrelated question.

Comment: As i had feared. Thank you!